# Exercise 7.10 from Isaac's Character Theory of Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, characters

I am having difficulty solving a problem in Martin Isaac's Character Theory of Finite Groups. Could someone please give me a hint?Thanks in advance!

The problem is as follows:

Let $K$ be T.I.F.N in $G$ and assume that $\mathfrak{J}=\{\psi\in Irr(N(K)):K\nsubseteq ker(\psi)\}$ is coherent. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the corresponding set of exceptional characters of $G.$ Let $M=\bigcap_{\chi\in\mathcal{T}} ker(\chi).$ Show that $M\cap K=1.$

Comment: There is a convention on this forum that, if you want help with a problem, then you should write down your own thoughts on how you think it might be possible to solve it. It might also be a good idea to provide the definitions of all of the technical terms. At the moment, the only people who will be able to help are people who have the book in front of them!